# Serializing IList<Guid> to MongoDB as a BsonString and not LUUID

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm having problems with List of guids stored in MongoDb. I would like to store them as strings and not LUUID entries.

Currently, I'm using BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String) attribute notation but I would like to replace it with initialization code so I can keep everything in one place.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;

namespace Program.Dto
{
    public class Node
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IList<Node> Groups { get; set; }
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
        public IList<Guid> Classes { get; set; }
        public static Node Create(string name)
        {
            return new Node
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Name = name,
                Groups = new List<Node>(),
                Classes = new List<Guid>()
            };
        }
    }
}
```

This is my initialization code:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Node>(cm =>
{
    cm.AutoMap();
    cm.SetIdMember(cm.GetMemberMap(c => c.Id));
    cm.GetMemberMap(c => c.Classes).SetSerializer(new GuidSerializer().WithRepresentation(BsonType.String));
});
```

But obviously I'm getting an error, cause it's a List not Guid itself.

```
System.ArgumentException: 'Value type of serializer is System.Guid  and does not match member type System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[[System.Guid, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].'
```

So, I probably need a custom serializer and came with something like that:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization;

namespace Program.MongoDB.BsonSerializers
{
    public sealed class GuidListSerializer : BsonSerializerBase<IList<Guid>>
    {
        public override IList<Guid> Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
        {
            var guids = new List<Guid>();

            var bsonReader = context.Reader;
            bsonReader.ReadStartDocument();
            bsonReader.ReadString();
            bsonReader.ReadStartArray();

            while (bsonReader.ReadBsonType() != BsonType.EndOfDocument)
            {
                var guid = new Guid(bsonReader.ReadBinaryData().Bytes);
                guids.Add(guid);
                bsonReader.ReadEndArray();
            }

            bsonReader.ReadEndDocument();

            return guids.AsReadOnly();
        }

//Override the serialize method for storing guids as strings?

    }
}
```

But I'm getting an error on bsonReader.ReadEndArray() and entry in MongoDb are store as LUUID and not String.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'ReadEndArray can only be called when State is EndOfArray, not when State is Value.'
```

I would like to be able to store Guids as strings and not using attribute.

```
[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
```

Comment: Shouldn't the ReadEndArray() be outside the loop? It seems that if the list is longer than 1 item, your will get an exception in ReadEndArray since you're calling it after each Guid item.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the state of the reader, and only read the end of array when the state is suitable:

```
while (bsonReader.State != BsonReaderState.EndOfArray)
{
    var guid = new Guid(bsonReader.ReadBinaryData().Bytes);
    guids.Add(guid);
}

bsonReader.ReadEndArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In the meantime, I abandoned the whole thing and I'm not going to store Guids as strings anymore. However, I found a quick explanation of how the BsonReader works here (I know it's Java but I guess it works in the same way in .net): https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.2/bson/readers-and-writers/